# R How to extract vector of integers from multi-list data structure

Tags: r, list, sapply

I am working in R, trying to extract a vector of numbers from a list data structure.  Here is a small reproducible example that reflects the structure of a much larger dataset.

```
# Create a reproducible example multi-level list structure 
mylist <- list()
mylist$`1` <- c("barcodes","data")
mylist$`2` <- c("barcodes","data")
mylist$`3` <- c("barcodes","data")
mylist$`1`$barcodes <- c(1:50)
mylist$`2`$barcodes <- c(50:200)
mylist$`3`$barcodes <- c(1:200)
```

I am able to successfully generate the data I need here called `numbers` using the following command. However this requires that I hard code each dataset of interest which is not ideal.

```
numbers <- c(mylist$`1`$barcodes[1:5],
             mylist$`3`$barcodes[1:5])

#This does achieve the desired result 
#> numbers
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

I am trying to do this in a high throughput way without hardcoding. Below is my attempt.

```
nums_of_interest <- c(1,3)
numbers <- c(gsub(" ", "", paste("mylist$'",nums_of_interest,"'$barcodes[1:5]")))

# This does not achieve the desired result
#> numbers
#[1] "mylist$'1'$barcodes[1:5]" "mylist$'3'$barcodes[1:5]"
```

I am struggling to identify a way to extract the numbers of interest `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5` of interest in a high throughput way.

Comment: Use bracketing `[[...]]` instead of dollar sign qualifier for more dynamic referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `lapply`. The first line extracts `"barcodes"` from your list, it returns a list.

```
lst <- lapply(mylist, `[[`, "barcodes")
```

Now we almost do the same again when we extract the first 5 entries from a subset of `lst`, i.e. from `lst[nums_of_interest]`.

```
nums_of_interest <- c(1, 3)
(numbers <- lapply(lst[nums_of_interest], `[`, 1:5))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#
#$`3`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Since `numbers` is a list but you want a vector in return use `unlist` (and `unname`) to get desired output.

```
unname(unlist(numbers))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

Or in one line with credits to @avid_useR

```
unname(unlist(lapply(mylist[nums_of_interest], function(x) x[['barcodes']][1:5])))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `map`:

```
library(purrr)

num_of_interst <- c(1,3)
numbers <- unlist(map(mylist[num_of_interst], ~.[["barcodes"]][1:5]))
```